# Flatten whilst splitting into smaller objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

I am having these kind of array structure.

```
[{ "primary_product": "Blueberry", 
   "list_of_products": ["Raspberry","Strawberry","Blackberry"]}]
```

I want to destructure the pattern and make it like this below

```
[{"id": 1,"value":"Blueberry"},{"id": 2,"value":"Raspberry"},{"id": 3,"value":"Strawberry"}, …]
```

Primary product will be the first product and then make the array of strings into key/value pair. How to do this using es6?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need is basic functions like forEach and push. I would recommend learning these.

```
let arr1 = [{ "primary_product": "Blueberry", "list_of_products": ["Raspberry","Strawberry","Blackberry"]}]

arr2 = [{ id: 1, value: arr1[0].primary_product }]
arr1[0].list_of_products.forEach((element) => {
    arr2.push({ id: arr2.length + 1, value: element })
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a one-liner using `map` on the `list_of_products`:

```
const arr = ['Raspberry','Strawberry','Blackberry'];
return arr.map((val, i) => {return {id: i+1, value: val}});
```

This is the result:

```
[
  { id: 1, value: 'Raspberry' },
  { id: 2, value: 'Strawberry' },
  { id: 3, value: 'Blackberry' }
]
```

Note that the callback to `map` includes `(currentValue, index, arr)`.

Answer (score 0):

To make things slightly easier for the eyes I've simplified the structure:

```js
const p = [ { a: 100, b: [101, 102, 103]}
          , { a: 200, b: [201, 202, 203]}];
```

You can flatten all the numbers into a single list i.e. `[100, 101, 102, 103, 200, 201, 202, 203]` with:

```js
p.flatMap(({a, b}) => [a, ...b]);
```

To get closer to what you're after, let's first create an `id` function that will return the next number:

```js
const id = (n => () => ++n)(0);
id(); //=> 1
id(); //=> 2
id(); //=> 3
// …
```

Then let's create a function `obj` that takes an `x` and wraps it into an object:

```js
const obj => x => ({id: id(), value: x});
obj(100); //=> {id: 1, value: 100);
obj(200); //=> {id: 2, value: 200);
// …
```

Then you can do:

```js
p.flatMap(({a, b}) => [obj(a), ...b.map(obj)]);
//=> [ {id: 1, value: 100}
//=> , {id: 2, value: 101}
//=> , {id: 3, value: 102}
//=> , {id: 4, value: 103}
//=> , {id: 5, value: 200}
//=> , {id: 6, value: 201}
//=> , {id: 7, value: 202}
//=> , {id: 8, value: 203}]
```